# Checkbox Column Allow one value

Tags: column, sharepoint-on-prem

How to make a checkbox column not to allow multiple values
Only check one option!

Would appreciate any help

Comment: Why don't you use radiobuttons for this.

Comment: They Require checkboxes not radiobuttons

Comment: Which version of SharePoint?

Comment: You should try to teach Them what checkboxes and radiobuttons are for. Convince them that it's not worth the effort doing it differently.

Comment: 2013 Sharepoint @Aveenav

Comment: You Know how clients are if they want something they wont change it I tried convincing them @ExpectedException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on SP 2013, use JSLink and add the jquery/javascript to allow selection of one checkbox (in post Render handler) the NewForm and EditForm.

SP renders the checkboxes within individual TDs that have a parent table with your column name + guid. For ex. If you have a column named 'MyCheckbox' MyCheckbox_e43ed65a-00e8-4560-b59c-c7fa0f923a4d_MultiChoiceTable. Use jQuery to bind an event to all children checkboxes and do a count. If selected checkboxes is greater than 1, return false on other checkbox click event.

Here's a sample script:

```
$("input[id^='MyCheckbox_']").on('click', function () {
    var count = $("table[id^='MyCheckbox_'] [type='checkbox']:checked").length;
    window.console && console.log(count);
    if (count > 1)
        return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this through javascript if you want, as it's pretty easy to just hide boxes.  I'll write an example.  Let's say your checkboxes are defined by the name "col_checkbox".

```
var target = document.getElementsByName("col_checkbox");  //Now we have all the checkboxes in a node array
var checkFlag = false;
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

  if(target[i].checked) {   //cycle through all boxes, seeing if one is checked
    checkFlag = true;
    for(j = 0; j < i; j++) {
       target[j].style.display = 'none';
       }
    for(k = i; k < 5; k++) {
       target[k].style.display = 'none';
       }

    //So we found one that is checked, and we hide all the other boxes
    //And if no value found, checkFlag is false
    }
 }

 if(!checkFlag) {
   for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      target[i].style.display = 'block';  //if no box checked, display all boxes
      }
```

Pretty simple in design, just tailor it to your needs.

Comment: Posted my answer after I saw you marked the correct one.  Either way, I'll leave it up for future reference.